# Parse key/value pair from JSON dictionary result in MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, dictionary

I've scoured through the posts here and haven't found a solution that works...

I am using JQuery autocomplete for a dropdown list of employees. I am able to load the list with values but it contains the keys from the dictionary that I am passing and not the values. I want to show both.

Controller code:

```
public JsonResult GetEmp(string id)
    {
        if (id.Length > 3)
        {
            var result = Json(repository.SearchForEmployee(id), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            return result;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Jquery code:

```
    $('.empId').keyup(function () {
    var x = $('.empId').val();
    var arrayValues = [];
    $.ajax({
        url: '../../Employee/GetEmployee',
        type: "Get",
        data: { id : x },
        cache: false,
        datatype: 'json',
        traditional: true,
        success: function (result) {
            $.each(result, function (item) {
                arrayValues.push(item);
            })
            $(".empId").autocomplete({
            source: arrayValues
        });
        },

        error: function (err) {
            alert('Foo')
        }
    });
});
```

JSON result variable in Controller action when debugging:

```
[0]  {[12345, Sharon Moore]}
[1]  {[12346, Amy Adams]}
[2]  {[12349, Adam Smith]}
```

Actual contents of JScript array for automplete:

```
12345, 24563, 84565
```

Can anyone explain why it is only bringing in the first value(key)?  Both key and value are strings.
Thanks again in advance...

Comment: Do you need quotes around your value strings?

Comment: What do you see when you `console.log(result)` in your `success` callback?

Comment: console. log results are:{"1289":"KIRK BELL","1827":"LINDA JONES","1963":"LINDA SMITH"}

Comment: That looks like an object and not an array or array of objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are returning an object and not an array you could try something like this:

```
var array_of_objects = [];
for (var key in result) {
   var val = result[key];
    //Now you have your key and value which you 
    //can add to a collection that your plugin uses
   var obj = {};
   obj.label = key;
   obj.value = val;
   array_of_objects.push(obj);
}

$(".empId").autocomplete({
     source: array_of_objects
});
```

Alternatively, you could just return an ArrayList in your C# code (which will be an array of objects/records). Here is some sample code from one of my projects:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult GetProject(int id) {
            string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Conn"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);

            string sql = "SELECT * FROM [Portfolio] WHERE [id] = @id";
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);
            da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@id", id));
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            conn.Open();
            da.Fill(dt);
            da.Dispose();
            conn.Close();

            return Json(objConv.DataTableToArrayList(dt), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

`objConv` is a helper utility I use. Here is the code for the `DataTableToArrayList` method I am using in the above code sample:

```
public ArrayList DataTableToArrayList(DataTable dataTbl) {

            ArrayList arrList = new ArrayList();

            foreach (DataRow dRow in dataTbl.Rows) {
                Hashtable recordHolder = new Hashtable();
                foreach (DataColumn column in dataTbl.Columns) {
                    if (dRow[column] != System.DBNull.Value) {
                        recordHolder.Add(column.ToString(), dRow[column].ToString());
                    } else {
                        recordHolder.Add(column.ToString(), "");
                    }
                }
                arrList.Add(recordHolder);
            }

            return arrList;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

JQuery UI Autocomplete expects a specific data structure to work.

SearchForEmployee must return a list of data in this format:

```
public class EmployeeAutocomplete
{
   public string @label { get; set; }
   public string @value { get; set; }
}
```

Or you need to convert in the javascript to that format instead of a list of arrays:

```
success: function (result) {
        $.each(result, function (item) {
            arrayValues.push(new { label: item[1], value: item[0] });
        });
        $(".empId").autocomplete({
            source: arrayValues
        });
    },
```

Autocomplete reference: http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Answer (score 1):

jQuery UI Autocomplete can make the ajax call itself, so I don't really see why you are making the ajax call separately.

```
$("#txtbox").autocomplete({
    source: url
});
```

Regardless of that though, the json from your controller should be returned in the format of `[ { label: "Choice1", value: "value1" }, ... ]` if you want to send value and labels back.

http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source

Comment: the results are being returned as {"1289":"KIRK BELL","1827":"LINDA JONES","1963":"LINDA SMITH"} . How do I get them into the format: [ { label: "Choice1", value: "value1" }, ... ]

Comment: That is one big object, not the array of objects that jquery ui autocompelete expects. On glance, without digging into the c# code, you need to return a c# list object that is serialized into json

Answer (score 1):

Here's a piece of code that i am using in a couple of places. I am not using the autocomplete feature that you are using but i dont think that is a problem.

Client Side:

```
    $.getJSON('../../Employee/GetEmployee', { id: x }, function (results) {
        var yourDropdown = $('#YourDropdown');
        var json = JSON.parse(results);
        $.each(json, function (index, item) {
            yourDropdown.append($('<option/>', {
                value: item.Value,
                text: item.Text
            }));
        });

        //Implement the autocomplete feature.
    });
```

Server Side:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult GetElements(int id)
    {
        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> elements;

        //Some routine that gets the elements goes here.

        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        return Json(serializer.Serialize(elements), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

I have not tested the code in your particular scenario but it should work since I am using the code snippet in multiple places.

Note: Try using the **getJson** method instead of **$.ajax**. It is a shortcut to the ajax implementation you are using. As you can see, the code is less verbose and more readable.